# Normalizers and Clifford group, how are they connected? (Nielsen and Chuang Ex 10.40)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, clifford-algebra

I was studying stabilizer formalism and came across with normalizers and Clifford group and I was trying to prove that any unitary operators that map Pauli group to Pauli group may be composed of $O(n^2)$ Hadamard, phase and CNOT gates. This was proven by one of the exercises from Nielsen and Chuang and this was Exercise 10.40 from the textbook:

> **Exercise 10.40**
>
> 1. Prove that the Hadamard and phase gates can be used to perform any normalizer operation on a single qubit.
> 2. Suppose $U$ is an $n+1$ qubit gate in $N(G_{n+1})$ such that $UZ_1 U^{\dagger} = X_1 \otimes g$ and $U X_1 U^{\dagger} = Z_1 \otimes g'$ for some $g,g' \in G_n.$ Define $U'$ on $n$ qubits by $U'| \psi \rangle \equiv \sqrt{2} \langle0|U(|0\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle$. Use the inductive hypothesis to show that the construction for $U$ in Figuire 10.9 may be implemented using $O(n^2)$ Hadmard, phase, and CNOT gates.
>
> 3. Show that any gate $U\in N(G_{n+1})$ may be implemented using $O(n^2)$ Hadamard, phase and CNOT gates

Progress: I have done number 1. by mapping all the Pauli matrices to Pauli matrices by Hadamard and phase gates but I have no idea how to start 2 or 3. May I please get advise on 2 and 3? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You might get a more robust response from this SE: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/